# Plotting multiple graphs of regression into one figure

Tags: r, matrix, regression

I am not expert in R and trying my best. I appreciate to have some assistance.

I have data as follows:

```
    POPs: num[1:3000] 3,4,5,6,7,....
    PM1:  num[1:3000] 3,4,5,6,7,....
    PM2:  num[1:3000] 3,4,5,6,7,....
    PM3:  num[1:3000] 3,4,5,6,7,....
    PM4:  num[1:3000] 3,4,5,6,7,....
.. etc
```

[image]

I want to do regression analysis for each PMs (PM1, PM2, PM3, ..) and put them into one figure (as in the picture)[image] . Also, adding into them the R2 , RMSE, MAE and the regression abline and 1:1 line.

The x is POPs and the y is PM1 and PM2 and PM3 ... etc.

I can do for each PMs (y-axis) individually in the code (aes(x=POPs, y=PM1)). However, it takes lot of figures and better to combine them in one figure. How I can add all the PMs into a single (y) in the code. I think some advance in looping which I am not into this level unfortunately.

```
ggplot(data =Plot,aes(x=POPs, y=PM1)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x) +
  geom_point(size=0.3) +
  stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)), # adds R^2 value
           r.accuracy = 0.01,
           label.x = 0, label.y = 375, size = 4) +
  stat_regline_equation(aes(label = ..eq.label..), # adds equation to linear regression
                        label.x = 0, label.y = 400, size = 4)
```

Based on Behnam Hedayat Answer below with some coding modification from my side and from Allan Cameron .. I can say now it worked 100% perfectly

```
# change format of df to longer
Plot %>%  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("PEM"), names_to = "PEMs", values_to = "PEMs_value") -> df2

df2 %>% ggplot(aes(POPs, PEMs_value)) +
  geom_point(color = "#fe4300", size=0.3) +
  geom_abline()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', se=FALSE, formula = y ~ x, color = "#1b14fd")+
  labs(y = expression(bold(PLF~PM["2.5"]~("u"*g/m^"3"))), x = expression(bold(POPS~PM["2.5"]~("u"*g/m^"3")))) +
  stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)), # adds R^2 value
           r.accuracy = 0.01,
           label.x = 0, label.y = 110, size = 3) +
  stat_regline_equation(aes(label = ..eq.label..), # adds equation to linear regression
                        label.x = 0, label.y = 100, size = 3) +
  facet_wrap(~PEMs, ncol=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Look into `facet_grid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `facet_wrap` function of `ggplot2`, but first you have to reshape your dataset to longer format by `pivot_longer()` function of `tidyverse`.
To add regression metrics on plots, you can create a separate data frame containing metrics of each group of PMs variable, then use this data frame in `geom_text` function with `x` and `y` column created for x and y position respectively.

Here I also used `caret` package functions (`R2`, `RMSE`, `MAE`) to calculate regression metrics.

```r
# caret for calculating R2, MAE and RMSE
# tidyverse to reshape data to longer format
libs <- c("ggplot2", "tidyverse","caret")
suppressMessages(invisible(sapply(libs, library, character.only=T)))

# sample dataset
df <- data.frame(POPs = sample(1:100, 100),
                 PM1 = sample(1:100, 100),
                 PM2 = sample(1:100, 100),
                 PM3 = sample(1:100, 100),
                 PM4 = sample(1:100,100),
                 PM5 = sample(1:100,100),
                 PM6 = sample(1:100,100),
                 PM7 = sample(1:100,100),
                 PM8 = sample(1:100,100))


# change format of df to longer
df %>%  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("PM"),
                     names_to = "PMs", values_to = "PMs_value") -> df2

head(df2, 10)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>     POPs PMs   PMs_value
#>    <int> <chr>     <int>
#>  1     5 PM1          88
#>  2     5 PM2          21
#>  3     5 PM3          51
#>  4     5 PM4          40
#>  5     5 PM5          40
#>  6     5 PM6           2
#>  7     5 PM7          30
#>  8     5 PM8          70
#>  9    52 PM1          13
#> 10    52 PM2          90

# create  a dataframe of summary of regression metrics
summary_df <- df2 %>%
  group_by(PMs) %>%
  summarise(R2 = R2(PMs_value, POPs),
            RMSE=RMSE(PMs_value, POPs),
            MAE=MAE(PMs_value, POPs)) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round,digits=2) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -PMs, names_to = "Metric", values_to = "Metric_value") %>%
  # add x column for x position of text and y column for y position
  mutate(x = rep(30, times =nrow(.)),
         y = rep(c(90,80,70), times=nrow(.)/3)) %>%
  unite("Metric", Metric:Metric_value, sep = " = ")

summary_df
#> # A tibble: 24 × 4
#>    PMs   Metric           x     y
#>    <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 PM1   R2 = 0.03       30    90
#>  2 PM1   RMSE = 43.95    30    80
#>  3 PM1   MAE = 36.72     30    70
#>  4 PM2   R2 = 0.02       30    90
#>  5 PM2   RMSE = 37.83    30    80
#>  6 PM2   MAE = 29.76     30    70
#>  7 PM3   R2 = 0.02       30    90
#>  8 PM3   RMSE = 43.69    30    80
#>  9 PM3   MAE = 36.88     30    70
#> 10 PM4   R2 = 0.01       30    90
#> # … with 14 more rows

df2 %>% ggplot(aes(POPs, PMs_value)) +
  geom_point(size=0.3) +geom_abline()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', se=FALSE)+
  facet_wrap(~PMs, ncol=4)+
  geom_text(data = summary_df,
            mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = Metric))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: your explanation of each step is totally excellent, especially for me that had no advanced knowledge of R packages. I gained reach knowledge from you.  Still when I run the regression metrics code my results ended with NAs.

Comment: This is  because you have NA values in your dataset, if this is the case , at first you have to impute NA character with some values  or just remove NAs by `df %>% drop_na() %>% pivot_longer(...`

Comment: Behnam I just played with your codes and added the codes that I posted in my question. It now worked perfectly . I updated my question above mentioning your solution strategy. Many thanks

Comment: I removed the NA, and worked more than perfectly. At least it included not only the R2 but also the RMSE and MAE information showed up as well.   I appreciate your help. I gained a lot of skills.

Comment: Is this part (y = rep(c(90,80,70))  shifts the regression metrics text position ?

Comment: Yes in **y axis**

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get your data into the correct format - that is, to pivot it into long format, such that the PM column names are in a single column, and the values are in their own column too. Then you can use the names column as a faceting variable in ggplot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Plot %>%
  pivot_longer(-POPs) %>%
  ggplot(aes(POPs, value)) +
  geom_abline() +
  geom_point(color = "#fe4300", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = y ~ x, color = "#fd1b14") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 100)) +
  facet_wrap(.~name, nrow = 5, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously we don't have your data (unless we were to transcribe the *picture* of your data or include the output of `dput(Plot)` in your question, so I have constructed a dummy data set with the same names and structure as your own:

```r
set.seed(1)

Plot <- setNames(as.data.frame(cbind(1:115, 
                 replicate(17, sample(100, 115, TRUE)))),
                 c("POPs", paste0("PM", 1:17)))

str(Plot)
#> 'data.frame':    115 obs. of  18 variables:
#>  $ POPs: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ PM1 : int  68 39 1 34 87 43 14 82 59 51 ...
#>  $ PM2 : int  1 29 78 22 70 28 37 61 46 67 ...
#>  $ PM3 : int  99 77 57 71 25 31 37 92 28 62 ...
#>  $ PM4 : int  60 65 64 53 5 44 35 23 29 35 ...
#>  $ PM5 : int  48 7 27 43 9 8 86 45 6 27 ...
#>  $ PM6 : int  65 2 9 49 69 91 93 66 31 78 ...
#>  $ PM7 : int  50 89 8 54 31 69 12 30 9 66 ...
#>  $ PM8 : int  21 7 99 42 33 94 5 5 4 11 ...
#>  $ PM9 : int  22 56 58 55 99 96 5 52 47 55 ...
#>  $ PM10: int  84 84 55 98 73 47 13 5 63 3 ...
#>  $ PM11: int  41 83 91 7 78 32 49 14 92 84 ...
#>  $ PM12: int  16 39 37 15 24 97 56 62 69 100 ...
#>  $ PM13: int  94 69 53 37 70 57 50 51 18 29 ...
#>  $ PM14: int  79 40 11 67 25 54 21 34 59 46 ...
#>  $ PM15: int  5 89 74 34 47 85 29 24 46 98 ...
#>  $ PM16: int  44 22 57 63 7 95 46 66 4 92 ...
#>  $ PM17: int  38 57 48 75 8 28 21 2 84 95 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Worked perfectly. The missing part yet is adding the (R2, RMSE, MAE) regression metrics.